# Allow jQuery plugin to render html in node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

I'm building a tournament site and found a great jQuery library that takes care of the bracket creation: [jQuery Bracket](http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/)

Unfortunately, since this is a JavaScript plugin it uses DOM-manipulation to render what I want to show. I've been looking for a way to allow it to render the HTML in node.js which I can then serve (kind of like a template engine such as jade but for jQuery instead) but I haven't found anything.

Since jQuery (and JavaScript in general) libraries are common, I feel like someone should've already found a way to use them on the server to render the content as static HTML instead of as a dynamic JavaScript in the client.

Comment: why don't you return the json with node and use the plugin in the client side?

Comment: I do that as well, but I want it to render server side as a fallback for non-js clients. I think it's good architecture.

Comment: an example of non-js client?

Comment: @rogelio A browser with js support turned off

Answer (score 0):

maybe yo can try something like this (not tested):

```
var $ = window.jQuery;
var el = $('<div></div>').bracket({init: the_data });
```

Now, the html generated by the brakets plugin is accesible doing

```
$(el).html()
```

Also, you can read this useful [tutorial](http://blog.davidpadbury.com/2010/10/03/using-nodejs-to-render-js-charts-on-server/), how to render a javascript chart using nodejs